# How to display Facebook Marketplace on web-based interface?

Tags: facebook

So far it has been quite the trick trying to figure out how to display the Facebook Marketplace that is easily accessible on the Facebook mobile app:

[image: Facebook Marketplace]

How can this be accessed on the desktop web interface for Facebook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook have now launched Marketplace on the desktop and can be accessed via the following link : https://www.facebook.com/marketplace/

Comment: That's really great to hear, thanks for letting us all know!

Answer (score -1):

It can't be accessed via the Desktop at this time.  Although I'm quite the in this level of bypass.  I wasn't able to get anywhere.  I figured the first step would be trying to capture the http requests outbound but the facebook app is obviously using https encryption.  And their app prevents a man in the middle attack.  I didn't dive further to modify the android OS to turn off the protection for man in the middle.  So at this point, unless someone does that and releases information on the API that is used.  We aren't getting anywhere.  Which personally, sucks as I always have soo many issues with the built in app.  The past week I've been unable to return anything older than the first results that show up in a search, it just spins forever.  If I load via category that is fine.  But still annoying.  For awhile I wasn't even able to do searches.  Very frustrating that its phone app only.

Answer (score -1):

Bluestacks android emulator, install facebook. Use it myself for desktop marketplace with copy/paste function

Comment: That's a good idea. Not ideal, but probably best option thus far!

Answer (score -2):

You can't. Marketplace is only available on mobile (iOS and Android). http://newsroom.fb.com/news/2016/10/introducing-marketplace-buy-and-sell-with-your-local-community/

Comment: Hmm, do you think the API would facilitate building such an app ourselves that uses their search tool? It seems that their search system ALMOST matches up with this marketplace function, but not 1-1.